# How to remap URL in two types of scenarios?

Tags: .htaccess

When someone goes on

`example.com/e/t/`

I want it to remap to `example.com/e/index.php?mode=t`

I also want it to redirect when it is

`example.com/e/t/y/`

I want it to remap to `example.com/e/index.php?mode=t&type=y`

My current code is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^e/(.*)/(.*)/$ e/index.php?mode=$1&type=$2
```

I know how to do one or the other but not both at the same time, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^e/(.*)/(.*)/$ e/index.php?mode=$1&type=$2
RewriteRule ^e/(.*)/$ e/index.php?mode=$1
```